# Does pointing an MX Record to a server allow it to send mail as well?

Tags: domains, dns, email, mx

I'm using Google Apps for Business with my domain for emails.

I have MX Records configured to point to Google's Mail servers. I understand why this lets me receive emails on Google Mail. By default I can also reply using the same domain.

How is this accomplished only by using the MX Record? Wouldn't Google need to be the server that the domain is on, or at least have the information of an outgoing SMTP server on that domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MX records have nothing to do with sending mail.

Anybody can send mail that appears to come from your domain. DNS records can now be used to authenticate official mail sending servers.   The records for that are DKIM or SPF records.   See: https://wordtothewise.com/2012/10/setting-up-dns-for-sending-email/

Google has documentation for setting up DKIM with G Suite (Google Apps):
https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=en

And for setting up SPF:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786

Comment: Makes sense, as I setup an SPF record as well. Without the SPF record some providers may choose to say "Sent on behalf of" though I believe.